# Unslider first dot always active

Tags: jquery, css, slider, gallery

am having a problem with unsliders dot indicators to show which slide is visible.
The current site with the problem is visible here: [cjeffryes.comoj.com](http://cjeffryes.comoj.com)

The problem is that the first dot is always active, even when another slide is selected it is a solid colour, have listed css only to keep it short but all other code is visible from the link above.
Hope someone can help.

CSS:

```
.banner
{
position:absolute;
margin-top:100px;
}

.banner li
{
list-style: none;
min-height:300px;
min-width:960px;
overflow:auto;
float:left;
}

.banner ul
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float:left;
}

.dots {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.dots li {
display: inline-block;
min-height:0px;
min-width:0px;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
margin: 0 4px;
text-indent: -999em;
border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .4;
-webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
-moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.dots li.active {
background: #000000;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `<ol class="dots">` seems to be appearing twice. It updates the active class fine on the first instance, but not on the 2nd occurrence of the dots ol.

Comment: Hi Nick, any idea of a solution. I suspected it to be more to do with the javascript but it shouldnt be as its straight from the unslider website.

Comment: For a quick CSS fix, you could do something like `.dots + .dots { display:none }` - And that will hide the 2nd occurrence.

Comment: Oh - it looks like the slider is being initialised twice. You have `$('.banner').unslider();` and `var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();`

Comment: Ah I see, Ive removed the CSS fix and the first instance you mentioned and its working fine now. Thanks a lot Nick much appreciated. Make sure you submit as an answer ill tick it as the correct answer.